# how to access my post class with one to one relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am new in Laravel. I have two classes(User,Post) and I want to call Post class from User class by using one to one relationship, hasOne(namespace).is it possible?It is same as below link video but code is different.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr28pSlqzV8&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEb-tzSN99Zy-39Y1tKl5DB&index=3
here is my **User** class

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Post;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function post(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
    }
}
```

This is **routes.php**

```
  Route::get('/user/{id}/post',function ($id){
    return User::find($id)->post->content;

});
```

my **Post** class

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use  SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates=['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable=[
        'title',
        'content'
    ];}
```

here i called get method using **User** class and i want to retrieve ***posts table*** content column (which is from **Post class**) 
i want know how to do because i run this code i got an error
**at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\app\Http\routes.php', '144', array('id' => '1')) in routes.php line 144**
**here is tables**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if this is a blog I'd make user hasMany posts ... not just one.

Comment: @Sherif i want to use one to one hasOne(), how i can................?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would have to see Post class to be sure, but my guess is that the tables are simply empty. The user has no posts, so User::find($id)->post is null, and then you try to get content property of it, which results in an error you got, as null is literally non-object :). Just generate some sample data to check if that's true.

Also, returning an object like that will not work:

```
// this will not work
return User::find($id)->post->content;

// do this in the testing phase to see if relationship works
return print_r(User::find($id)->post->content, true);
// or
dd(User::find($id)->post->content);
```

Otherwise you seem to be on the right track, keep going!

Comment: no bro,in both of table has data.above the code doesn't work.same error.i also updated my question with post class and error pic.i think iam unable to access **Post** class in hasOne function.can u plz help me :).

Comment: bro solved :) ,I added two more records with same user_id then it works but now also with 1 record doesn't work.anyway, it working.thank you